# How to combine multiple SQL files with different separators in one EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder?

Tags: spring, datasource, embedded-database

I need to setup an embedded database in order to run my test cases in a spring boot project.

I have separated my SQL scripts into two files in order to set different separators for them :

One contains my basic create table scripts (**NAME = create-table.sql, SEPARATOR = ;**) and the other contains the Stored procedures (**NAME = stored-procedures.sql, , SEPARATOR = /;**).

As per comments on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703866/hsqldb-stored-procedure/28718652#28718652), I can configure different separators for the two sql files by doing this in applicationContext.xml:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="mctDBDataSource" ignore-failures="DROPS" >    
  <jdbc:script location="classpath:databaseTesting/inMemory/createInMemoryDatabase.sql" separator=";"/>
  <jdbc:script location="classpath:databaseTesting/inMemory/createInMemoryDatabaseProcedures.sql" separator="/;"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

But in my case I am trying to use the non-XML approach as below.

```
public DataSource myDataSource(){
   return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().generateUniqueName(true)
   .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).addScript("create-table").setSeparator(";").setEncryptEncoding("UTF-8")
   .ignoreFiledDrops(true).build();
}
```

The above code works fine if I were to use only one SQL file.

How can I combine two SQL files with different separators so as to create one DataSource.

Doing this doesn't work :

```
public DataSource myDataSource(){
  return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().generateUniqueName(true)
  .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).addScript("create-table")
  .setSeparator(";").addScript("stored-procedures").setSeparator("/;")setEncryptEncoding("UTF-8")
  .ignoreFiledDrops(true).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with an `EmbeddedDatabaseFactor` directly, but you can use one script in the `EmbeddedDatabaseFactor` and then use a fresh `ResourceDatabasePopulator` to execute the second script on the database.